# Universal Image Loader Usage

Tags: android

My Application gets images by json/url and populate a ListView along some TextViews. On each item click a new details_activity is open with an ImageView to display the image from the row. Then I open this image from ImageView in a new activity with fullscreen size.

My question is: Do I need to use the Universal Image Loader code below on all activities mentioned above?

```
DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .cacheInMemory(true).cacheInMemory(true)
    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
    .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();

ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
    getApplicationContext())
    .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
    .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
    .diskCacheSize(52428800).build();

ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

What is happening is that sometimes I get out of memory error displaying fullscreen images. But if I return to details_activity and then click again on image, it opens with no error in fullscreen_activity, even if I use the code above on all activities that use imageloader.

Comment: You could use universal image loader to populate your listview. after that just pass the image url via intent to the nextactivity and set it to imageview.!

Comment: @DhinakaranThennarasu: Should I write the code on CustomListAdapter class or on ListView class?

Comment: @Skynet : Only defaultOptions or all the code (ImageLoaderConfiguration config...) ?

Comment: I am sorry the config needs to be loaded once, default options for each Class.

Comment: Tell me what you think: I did the way you told me. It works perfectly in genymotion with android 4.4. In android default emulator with android 4.0 the problem is happening sometimes. Yesterday I created an android default emulator with android L (Api 21) and it looked to work fine. Is this an emulator or API problem @Skynet?

Comment: You must use `Traceview` to get the details of all bottlenecks.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) and avoid the extra codes and memory issue.

**Example code (just 1 line!):**

```
Glide.with(this).load("http://goo.gl/gEgYUd").into(imageView);
```